# Python: How to get largest element in a set() in constant time?

Tags: python, set

In a C++ based set, you can read largest or the smallest element by using an iterator in constant time. 
Example:

```
std::set<int> exampleSet ;
exampleSet.insert(1);
exampleSet.insert(2);
exampleSet.insert(3);
std::set<int>::iterator it=exampleSet.end();
it--;
cout << *it << endl;
// prints: 3
```

How can we achieve the same in a Python set in constant time?

Comment: C++ `std::set`s support that because they're order-based. Python `set`s are hash-based, like `std::unordered_set`. They don't support that.

Comment: you can use another data structure, for example heap: https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html.

Comment: I gave an answer, but you need to think what's most important for you - if you need set behavior and O(1) min/max retrieval you'll have to implement yourself in Python.